# To to categorise by one variable in fetchAll group

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code which works. DB connection is defined earlier in the file and not relevant to show here. Safe to assume it's working correctly - because it is. :-)

```
try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE `type` = 'a' ORDER BY `title` DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
    $resultA = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }

if(count($resultA) == 0) {} else {
    // We have result(s) to show
    echo "  <h2>Section title in here</h2>\n\n";
    echo "  <p>";
    foreach ($resultA as $value) {
        echo "\n  &bull; <a href=\"".$value['uri']."\" target=\"_blank\">".$value['title']."</a><br>";
    }
    echo "</p>\n\n";
}
```

And this gives me an output - as expected since there is actually data in the DB to display - like this:

```
  <h2>Section title in here</h2>

  <p>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308496_2896806.pdf" target="_blank">2015 Annual Report</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308526_2307279.pdf" target="_blank">2014 Annual Report</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308872_1655063.pdf" target="_blank">2013 Audited Financial Accounts</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308568_3163307.pdf" target="_blank">2013 Annual Report</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308849_1956569.pdf" target="_blank">2012 Audited Financial Accounts</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308595_3408196.pdf" target="_blank">2012 Annual Report</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308834_1072958.pdf" target="_blank">2011 Audited Financial Accounts</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308615_1515719.pdf" target="_blank">2011 Annual Report</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308819_1044010.pdf" target="_blank">2010 Audited Financial Accounts</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308638_6083742.pdf" target="_blank">2010 Annual Report</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308737_1838789.pdf" target="_blank">2009 Audited Financial Accounts</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308671_1675927.pdf" target="_blank">2009 Annual Report</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308713_2363893.pdf" target="_blank">2008 Audited Financial Accounts</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308477_6178876.pdf" target="_blank">2008 Annual Report</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308421_966670.pdf" target="_blank">2007 Annual Report</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308393_535085.pdf" target="_blank">2006 Annual Report</a><br></p>
```

Now see how *some* of the output is different from most of it?

How can I simply separate out the items with "Audited Financial Accounts" within the title and then rearrange the displayed output so that it will become:

```
  <h2>Section title in here</h2>

  <div style="width: 50%; float: right;">

   <p>
   &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308872_1655063.pdf" target="_blank">2013 Audited Financial Accounts</a><br>
   &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308849_1956569.pdf" target="_blank">2012 Audited Financial Accounts</a><br>
   &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308834_1072958.pdf" target="_blank">2011 Audited Financial Accounts</a><br>
   &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308819_1044010.pdf" target="_blank">2010 Audited Financial Accounts</a><br>
   &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308737_1838789.pdf" target="_blank">2009 Audited Financial Accounts</a><br>
   &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308713_2363893.pdf" target="_blank">2008 Audited Financial Accounts</a><br></p>

 </div>

  <p>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308496_2896806.pdf" target="_blank">2015 Annual Report</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308526_2307279.pdf" target="_blank">2014 Annual Report</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308568_3163307.pdf" target="_blank">2013 Annual Report</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308595_3408196.pdf" target="_blank">2012 Annual Report</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308615_1515719.pdf" target="_blank">2011 Annual Report</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308638_6083742.pdf" target="_blank">2010 Annual Report</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308671_1675927.pdf" target="_blank">2009 Annual Report</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308477_6178876.pdf" target="_blank">2008 Annual Report</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308421_966670.pdf" target="_blank">2007 Annual Report</a><br>
  &bull; <a href="./lib/rep/REP_1459308393_535085.pdf" target="_blank">2006 Annual Report</a><br></p>
```

Please keep in mind I am **not** a php guru. But I am trying to get there, so be patient with me in your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it within the php. Check my code and see if it works ok for you. This is written using your original code and modifying it to (hopefully) produce the result you want.

```
try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE `type` = 'a' ORDER BY `title` DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
    $resultA = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);       
} catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }

if(count($resultA) == 0) {} else {
    // We have material to show. First set up the arrays to divide output into
    $posRight = array(); // array of output to float right
    $posNormal = array(); // array of output not floating right
    echo "  <h2>Section title in here</h2>\n\n";

    foreach($resultA as $value) {
        if (strpos($value['title'], 'Audited Financial Accounts') !== FALSE) {
            // We have the "Audited Financial Accounts" items returning here. Add these results into the $posRight array
            $posRight[] = $value;
        } else {
            // The rest of the result content arrives here. Add it to the $posNormal array
            $posNormal[] = $value;
        }
    }

    // We have our two arrays, output the float right results first
    echo "  <div style=\"width: 50%; float: right;\">";
    foreach($posRight as $value) {
        echo "\n   &bull; <a href=\"".$value['uri']."\" target=\"_blank\">".$value['title']."</a><br>";
    }
    echo "\n  </div>\n\n";

    // Now output the other set
    echo "  <p>";
    foreach($posNormal as $value) {
        echo "\n   &bull; <a href=\"".$value['uri']."\" target=\"_blank\">".$value['title']."</a><br>";
    }
    echo "</p>\n\n";
}
```

You could also spit the results out an an unordered list with much the same result.

Comment: Thank you Cassandra, this resulted EXACTLY what I was looking for. And still with just one mysql query. :-)

Comment: Welcome df0. Looking at what Ash said, there seems to be nothing incorrect with your output code assuming it validates on whatever you are using (html 5?). There are many ways to reach a solution. None are definitively right or wrong. There are just better ones and not so good ones. I don't understand what Ash was trying to get to as his answer was not clear but it's possible using MySQL `GROUP BY` may be a way to a satisfactory result.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is:
**GROUP BY**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE `type` = 'a' GROUP BY `title`");
```

Comment: thanks but this does not produce anything remotely looking like the result wanted. It's actually quite messy, and I had to correct your code in a few places just to make it work.... :-/

Comment: Come to think of it, I could have the same output that this produces - from one query just by slightly modifying my original code!

Comment: Ah, well i was giving you just an idea what you have to do to make it work. And FYI, using <p> and \n is not a good practice. 
Look at 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables for proper ways of displaying results.

Comment: Looking for a concise and accurate answer to my question. Not wanting to be confused and shown how to take steps further away from my objective. I think that's the whole point of SO. Not wanting to be offensive but I'm here to get better, not have examples of bad php. Missing $ and omitting necessary sections of code - not good.

Comment: And no I don't need/require a table for my results. Though I am interested to see why - valid reason - producing a result inside a <p> is bad...?

Comment: OK, there you go!!
Valid reason: Better practice!! And bootstrapping is the way to go!

Comment: Can you please justify why going tables is apparently "better practice" over a simple cleaner less code mess method? The results are not tabular items.

Comment: Okay, i am not sure how I can make you understand. Presentation is important. If you look link i gave to you, it has tons of library on it. You can reference grids, nav bars , buttons, components etc. Basically, you make a whole site with using that library.

Comment: Ok but I don't NEED to do this. There is no good reason why I SHOULD do this over any other number of presentation solutions, right? So why, exactly, is my methodology supposedly bad or wrong, and your suggestion is supposedly right or better? I think you just have a different way or displaying results. I don't see it as being better than mine in any way at all. Anyway it's all off topic and not helping me with the question at all.

Comment: Too much irrelevant chatter, not enough solution

Comment: @cassandra why you downvoted me and why not enough solution? The answer you gave is just static and its not dynamic. The solution i gave to him was dynamic and would have worked for most cases. He complained about formatting. We are here to give idea, not to give him whole code and clean up his mess. In this age, if someone is coding with <p> /n and that's not a good practice. I was just advising him over good practice which BOOTSTRAP is.

Comment: @Ash Your code was bad, it did not work and it was extremely messy. These are level 1 things that you need to be getting right before you pick on someone elses methodology. You also completely ignored the question and went off on your tangent, which is only based on your opinion and not any hard fact. There is absolutely nothing wrong with defining paragraph opening and closing (<p></p>) within php output, and certainly nothing wrong with keeping the code clean and readable by defining carriage returns (\n). Your code needs a lot of improvement, however.